# Fetching details using awk in zenity list

Tags: 14.04, command-line, awk, zenity, youtube-dl

I am using youtube-dl to fetch videos and its format. this is my code

```
youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uvr1xiEaICU |awk 'NR > 5 { print}' | zenity  --list  --column "youtube"
```

And this is the result in listbox

```
249          webm       audio only DASH audio , opus @ 50k
250          webm       audio only DASH audio , opus @ 70k
251          webm       audio only DASH audio , opus @160k
140          m4a        audio only DASH audio  128k , m4a_dash container, aac  @128k (44100Hz), 4.21MiB
171          webm       audio only DASH audio  131k , audio@128k (44100Hz), 3.90MiB
160          mp4        256x138    DASH video  110k , 12fps, video only, 3.60MiB
278          webm       256x138    DASH video  113k , webm container, VP9, 12fps, video only, 2.82MiB
133          mp4        426x230    DASH video  252k , 24fps, video only, 8.10MiB
242          webm       426x230    DASH video  263k , 24fps, video only, 5.86MiB
243          webm       640x346    DASH video  482k , 24fps, video only, 10.34MiB
134          mp4        640x346    DASH video  609k , 24fps, video only, 13.93MiB
244          webm       854x462    DASH video  818k , 24fps, video only, 17.30MiB
135          mp4        854x462    DASH video 1114k , 24fps, video only, 27.40MiB
247          webm       1280x692   DASH video 1621k , 24fps, video only, 31.78MiB
136          mp4        1280x692   DASH video 2229k , 24fps, video only, 52.99MiB
17           3gp        176x144    
36           3gp        320x240    
5            flv        400x240    
43           webm       640x360    
18           mp4        640x360    
22           mp4        1280x720   (best)
```

The problem in the above code is that it publish all those data in a single column (youtube) inside zenity listbox. I want those details in separate columns in the list box

eg

```
 I            F            A             D              R

249     |     webm   |    audio only| DASH audio | opus @ 50k etc
```

where I,F, A, D, R are columns

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output for each line you want to see.

Answer (score 2):

### Here is your solution

```
youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v\=uvr1xiEaICU | sed 's/audio only/audio only  /' | awk -F'\\s{3,}| , ' 'NR>5 {for(i=1;i<=5;i++){print $i}}' | zenity --list --column="I" --column="F" --column="A" --column="D" --column="R"
```

### Explanation

The command

```
youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v\=uvr1xiEaICU
```

returns

```
[youtube] uvr1xiEaICU: Downloading webpage
[youtube] uvr1xiEaICU: Extracting video information
[youtube] uvr1xiEaICU: Downloading DASH manifest
[info] Available formats for uvr1xiEaICU:
format code  extension  resolution note
249          webm       audio only DASH audio , opus @ 50k
250          webm       audio only DASH audio , opus @ 70k
251          webm       audio only DASH audio , opus @160k
140          m4a        audio only DASH audio  128k , m4a_dash container, aac  @128k (44100Hz), 4.21MiB
171          webm       audio only DASH audio  131k , audio@128k (44100Hz), 3.90MiB
160          mp4        256x138    DASH video  110k , 12fps, video only, 3.60MiB
278          webm       256x138    DASH video  113k , webm container, VP9, 12fps, video only, 2.82MiB
133          mp4        426x230    DASH video  252k , 24fps, video only, 8.10MiB
242          webm       426x230    DASH video  263k , 24fps, video only, 5.86MiB
243          webm       640x346    DASH video  482k , 24fps, video only, 10.34MiB
134          mp4        640x346    DASH video  609k , 24fps, video only, 13.93MiB
244          webm       854x462    DASH video  818k , 24fps, video only, 17.30MiB
135          mp4        854x462    DASH video 1114k , 24fps, video only, 27.40MiB
247          webm       1280x692   DASH video 1621k , 24fps, video only, 31.78MiB
136          mp4        1280x692   DASH video 2229k , 24fps, video only, 52.99MiB
17           3gp        176x144    
36           3gp        320x240    
5            flv        400x240    
43           webm       640x360    
18           mp4        640x360    
22           mp4        1280x720   (best)
```

---

We need a list with some modifications:

```
sed 's/audio only/audio only  /' | awk -F'\\s{3,}| , ' 'NR>5 {for(i=1;i<=5;i++){print $i}}'
```

Output:

```
249
webm
audio only
DASH audio
opus @ 50k
250
webm
audio only
DASH audio
opus @ 70k
251
webm
audio only
DASH audio
opus @160k
140
m4a
audio only
DASH audio  128k
m4a_dash container, aac  @128k (44100Hz), 4.21MiB
171
webm
audio only
DASH audio  131k
audio@128k (44100Hz), 3.90MiB
160
mp4
256x138
DASH video  110k
12fps, video only, 3.60MiB
278
webm
256x138
DASH video  113k
webm container, VP9, 12fps, video only, 2.82MiB
133
mp4
426x230
DASH video  252k
24fps, video only, 8.10MiB
242
webm
426x230
DASH video  263k
24fps, video only, 5.86MiB
243
webm
640x346
DASH video  482k
24fps, video only, 10.34MiB
134
mp4
640x346
DASH video  609k
24fps, video only, 13.93MiB
244
webm
854x462
DASH video  818k
24fps, video only, 17.30MiB
135
mp4
854x462
DASH video 1114k
24fps, video only, 27.40MiB
247
webm
1280x692
DASH video 1621k
24fps, video only, 31.78MiB
136
mp4
1280x692
DASH video 2229k
24fps, video only, 52.99MiB
17
3gp
176x144


36
3gp
320x240


5
flv
400x240


43
webm
640x360


18
mp4
640x360


22
mp4
1280x720
(best)
```

---

And with `zenity`

```
zenity --list --column="I" --column="F" --column="A" --column="D" --column="R"
```

we have this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. but Its not working properly for me. this is the screen shot http://i.imgur.com/XWwuW6Q.png . And also can you explain your code

Comment: I have executed this code only `youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v\=uvr1xiEaICU | sed 's/audio only/audio only /' | awk -F'\\s{2,}|,' 'NR>5 {for(i=1;i<=5;i++){print $i}}' | zenity --list --column="I" --column="F" --column="A" --column="D" --column="R"`

Comment: Not working..I will upload the screenshot

Comment: This is the previous result http://i.imgur.com/VNqjFXt.png

Comment: `youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch\?v\=uvr1xiEaICU | sed 's/audio only/audio only  /' | awk -F'\\s{3,}| , ' 'NR>5 {for(i=1;i<=5;i++){print $i}}' | zenity --list --column="I" --column="F" --column="A" --column="D" --column="R"` same error as the previous command. can you expain your code then i can try to edit it.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't match with my screenshot. Have you tried the latest version in my answer?

Comment: @potholiday From what I understand , zenity takes a list, and counts items. Once it fills up required amount of columns it treats the next set of items as a new line. I'd suggest using a textbox, with the titles added. That's not ideas, of course, but . . . should work

Comment: @A.B. sorry for the late reply. I already up voted your answer but it only partially solved the problem hence not accepted. The problem i mentioned in my previous comments still exists. I don’t know whether its my systems problem or not, some third party should run the script and see the end result. May be i will ask this in chat